# Postgres 9.6 -> 14 using pglogical, autovacuum not running

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

We're upgrading our Postgresql from 9.6 to 14, using pglogical (latest installed via yum). The replication is working fine without errors. What we are not seeing, however, is any autovacuum activity on the v14 database, even though we continue to see normal autovacuum activity on the v9.6 database. Also, strangely, the dead tuple counts do not change on the v14 database and are mostly 0. I did run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the v14 database.

The command we are using to see autovacuum activity is
`SELECT relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_autoanalyze FROM pg_stat_user_tables;`

The command we are using to see dead tuple counts is
`SELECT relname, n_dead_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables;`

There's nothing in the logs except checkpoint notifications. Here is one line picked at random:

`2022-09-22 11:59:46 PDT [2877]: [15846-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 38220 buffers (0.9%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 17 recycled; write=269.923 s, sync=0.025 s, total=269.962 s; sync files=264, longest=0.007 s, average=0.001 s; distance=313936 kB, estimate=329901 kB`

The v14 database is streaming to another v14 database acting as a replica.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Dead tuples accumulate with UPDATE/DELETE  not INSERT/COPY. Are you just moving the data from 9.6 -> 14 or is the 9.6 in active use where it is replicating updates and deletes?

Comment: The v9.6 database is in heavy active use (the backend for a website), including UPDATES/DELETES. Deletes are being propagated.

Comment: 1) Does the Postgres log show any relevant information? 2) When you are querying  `pg_stat_user_tables` are you in the correct database? As that view is scoped to the current database.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs except checkpoint notifications (this node is not being used in production, but its streaming replica is being queried against). I've added a  representative checkpoint log line to the original question. We're replicating 6 databases on this node, and the behavior is the same for all 6.

Comment: Do you have track_counts turned off?

Comment: track_counts is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, it's clear that the `n_dead_tup` counts are not updated while pglogical replication is running. This also means that autovacuum never runs while pglogical replication is running. Restarting the v14 node causes the `n_dead_tup` counts to be updated and does trigger autovacuum, but that is a one time event (the tuples are not updated again until another restart).

Once you disable pglogical, the `n_dead_tup` counts are immediately updated, and autovacuum starts to work again as expected (even without a restart).